# Why a new element in the database doesn't want to assign itself to an existing foreign key but creates a new one?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a serious problem because the whole application is already written and one thing that I have no idea about does not work. The application was created in WPF and using EF with a code-first approach.

In short, the point is that each owner can have many dogs (one-to-many relationship). In the first window, the created owners are displayed (they are added to the database correctly). After clicking on the owner, you go to the next window where you can add his dogs. And here the problem arises - after creating a dog, it is not assigned to the previously selected owner, but a new owner is created with the same properties only with Id greater by 1.Additionally, the previously selected owner is saved in a static variable.

This is how the function that saves the given owner looks like after selecting it in the first window:

```
public void listOwnerForm_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SavedOwner = (OwnerModel)listOwnerForm.SelectedItem;
}
```

Then a new dog is created:

```
private void btnAddDogDogForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtNameDogForm.Text.Length > 0 || txtAgeDogForm.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        dog.DogName = txtNameDogForm.Text;
        dog.DogAge = txtAgeDogForm.Text;

        using (var db = new Model1())
        {
            dog.Owner = db.OwnerModels
                          .Where(x => x.OwnerId == OwnerForm.SavedOwner.OwnerId)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
         }

         if (cmbGenderDogForm.Text == "Male")
         {
             dog.DogGender = EnumGender.male;
         }
         else if (cmbGenderDogForm.Text == "Female")
         {
             dog.DogGender = EnumGender.female;
         }
         else
         {
             dog.DogGender = EnumGender.castrated;
         }

         if (cmbActivityDogForm.Text == "Small")
         {
             dog.ActivityDemand = EnumActivity.small;
         }
         else if (cmbActivityDogForm.Text == "Medium")
         {
             dog.ActivityDemand = EnumActivity.medium;
         }
         else
         {
             dog.ActivityDemand = EnumActivity.large;
         }
     }

     dog.SaveDogToBase();

     MessageBox.Show("Dog has been added.");
}
```

And finally the dog is saved in the database:

```
public void SaveDogToBase()
{
    Model1 db = new Model1();
    db.DogModels.Add(this);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But as you can see, the dog does not assign itself to the given person, but creates a new one each time:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZxDz.png)

This is what the SQL Server table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DogModels] 
(
    [DogId]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DogName]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DogAge]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DogSize]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [ActivityDemand] INT            NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionD]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DogGender]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [OwnerId]        INT            NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DogModels] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DogId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.DogModels_dbo.OwnerModels_OwnerId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([OwnerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[OwnerModels] ([OwnerId]) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_OwnerId]
ON [dbo].[DogModels]([OwnerId] ASC);
```

I don't have much experience with EF yet, so I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please help. It's just that you can add a couple of dogs to the owners.

Comment: I think we need to see your code first models. Feels like something is wrong there. Also `dog` is not defined anywhere in the code you present.

Comment: dog is defined at the beginning of the window - here it only shows one z button.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating a new DbContext in your save operation. That context is not tracking the Owner so it will treat it as a new Owner and insert with a new generated ID.

Because you are scoping a DbContext in the Button event handler to find the owner, this step is completely unnecessary. You can just put:

```
db.DogModels.Add(dog);
db.SaveChanges();
```

within that `using(db = new Model1())` where you populate a dog and load the owner and your new Dog will be saved with the associated owner.

Passing entities between DbContext scopes is not something I recommend. It leads to problems like this and others that can be a mess to sort out especially because they can happen seemingly intermittently at runtime.